# Keycloak - is it ready for production?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I spent time testing out Keycloak Identity server for handling microservice authentication using OpenID connect. I was able to fully customise the freemarker theme to what I want.

It's got nice features too but somehow I still find it buggy, most annoying error is getting

> "An error occurred, please login again through your application"

because the one time code is not valid on browser refresh.

[image]

I'm wondering if anyone is actually using it in production or it's just an Alpha release not ready for production yet ?

Current version: 2.5.0.Final

Comment: Have you tried to use the [rest api](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/rest-api/)? would be good if you have some example of code.

Comment: I'm using keycloak in some web applications. For some services, I'm using an api gateway called [apiman](http://www.apiman.io). This tool works integrated with keycloak and is really good to manage services.

Comment: @CelsoAgra the problem is not the rest api but Keycloak itself. It looks unstable - do you experience the error above and how did you fix it?

Comment: I never got this error. Is there more info in the server log file?

Comment: @CelsoAgra that's weird, am running in docker container but that should not be the problem. Basically, click on register page and refresh the page. The code becomes invalid and you get the error page - I attached screenshot

Comment: Try to run your docker container with this volume: `/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/log`. This error message is quite generic.

Comment: That's probably related to your client application being misconfigured rather than keycloak itself. Are you using some adapter? As per the title in the post, I would say it is definitely ready for production, I'm using it currently in a production stage. Best regards

Comment: There's also Redhat Single Signon if you would like a vednor-supported version for production.  Its currently 7.0 (based on Keycloak 1.9.8) however 7.1 is in Beta and this is based on keycloak 2.4.